# Shopware Extjs - How to open new window

Tags: extjs, shopware

I know how to open window when `extjs` files are in the same block view, under same subscriber and controller:

```
Ext.create('Shopware.apps.oprepare.view.multiPrepare.Window', {
     productNumbers: productNumbers
}).show();
```

**But this does not work**, if I want to open window defined in another folder under /backend/ . It means Another Controller controls it and another subscriber registers it.

How to do that?

**EDIT:**
With folowing:

```
Ext.create('Shopware.apps.Upload').show();
```

Request to php controller is sent, js gets loaded(I see it in response body) but after that I get error

```
Ext.create(...).show() is not a function.
```

I tried with:

```
Ext.create('Shopware.apps.Upload').launch();
```

Error is:

```
 windowManager.subwindows is udefined.
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This helped me:

```
Ext.create('Shopware.apps.Upload').init();
```